# How do I create variables without declaration in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Can I have python create variables on the fly, assuming the most reasonable filetype?

In other words, how do I avoid creating empty variables? In this loop, `i` doesn't seem to need an introduction, why does `list`?

```
list=[]
for i in other_list:
     list.append(i)
```

Comment: Please precisely define "most reasonable".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, you need something to append to. Since you're modifying something existing, that something needs to exist. `i` is not being modified.

Python does actually let you make lists inline without being previously instantiated though, it's called a `list comprehension`, and it works kind of like this:

```
dont_name_your_variables_list = [i*2 for i in range(10)]
```

EDIT: Another way of thinking of this, as mentioned by @BrenBarn would to be to think of it as being unable to do anything to a variable that does not yet have a value assigned to it.

First explanation:

```
i+1  # i does not yet exist, and since i+1 is a modification on i, this will not work
```

Second explanation:

```
i+1  # i has no value assign to it. Since i+1 is doing something to i, this will not work.
```

Comment: Also `list` is a reserved word in Python, so if you don't initialize it you'll get an error that is unlike the error you would get for any other uninitialized variable.

Comment: @dg99 There is a reason I used that particular variable name :)

Comment: It's not correct to say that the difference depends on whether you're "modifying" the variable.  `i + 1` doesn't modify `i`, but you still can't do that without assigning `i` a value first.

Comment: @BrenBarn We may have different definitions of the word modifying, I don't mean to imply it has anything to do with being in place, but `i+1` is a modification of `i`

Comment: @SlaterTyranus: Interesting.  Perhaps you should clarify what you mean by "modify" then.  I think it's simpler to say that you can't do anything to a variable that hasn't had a value assigned (except assign a value to it),

Comment: @BrenBarn updated, but done so in a way that I hope shows that the two explanations are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful. 
Just curious: is there a reason for python to not just assume `i` to be an integer of `0` when I say `i+5`? Or in this case if I say `append these items to this variable which you first must create based on the type of the first item in the list`?

Comment: @frogpool the problem is that there are a lot of ways to add five to a number, and someone doing `i+5` is much more likely to be an error than something intentional. There are languages which don't agree with this, but in general that is a bug, not a feature.

Answer (score 2):

The `for` loop *is* the declaration/introduction of `item`.  You don't have to declare variables, but every variable has to have a value.  You can't create a variable with no value, and you can't use a variable unless it has a value.

One way to assign a value is to do `someVar = blah`.  Another way is to do `for someVar in blah` -- that is, a `for` loop assigns a value to a variable, just like the `=` assignment does.  There are also other constructs in Python that assign values to variables, suc as `def` and `class`.

Both `list` and `item` have values assigned to them in your code, just in different ways.  What you can't do is try to do something to a variable that hasn't had a value assigned to it.

Answer (score 1):

You must explicitly create `list` because otherwise Python would have no idea what value it is supposed to have. The creation of `i` is allowed more implicit because the value of `i` is automatically determined by the list that you're looping over.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is [Syntactic Sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar).
The line

```
for i in list:
list.append(item)
```

is interpreted (in pseudocode) as

```
Create variable i
Set type of i to type of the first entry in list
While the list is not scanned through completely:
    Append item to the list.
```